# React Navigation 'beforeRemove' event is not getting fired in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to prevent user from going back by Android back button or gesture while a video is being recorded in React Native. As per [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back) of React Navigation, it should be handled with the `beforeRemove` event listener. But the event is never being fired when going back.

I tried with `blur`, it was getting fired though, but since this event doesn't have a `preventDefault()` method, it's not usable in this scenario.

React Navigation - v5.x

React Native - 0.63.2

Here's the sample code for the screen I am trying to achieve

```
const VideoCapturePage = ({navigation}) => {
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
      if (!isRecording) {
        return;
      }

      e.preventDefault();

      Alert.alert(
        'Unsaved changes',
        'There are unsaved changes. Please chose what you want.',
        [
          {
            text: 'Go back',
            onPress: () => {
              navigation.dispatch(e.data.action);
            },
          },
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            onPress: () => {
              console.log('cancelled');
            },
          },
          {
            text: 'Continue to Edit',
            onPress: () => {
              console.log('continue');
            },
          },
        ],
        {
          cancelable: false,
        },
      );
    });
  }, [navigation, isRecording]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <VideoCamera
        isRecording={isRecording}
        setIsRecording={setIsRecording}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Which version of React Navigation are you using?  It is not available in all versions of v5, only v5.7+.

Comment: Yes, I was using Reac Navigation version < 5.7.x. I upgraded all the React Navigation packages and it worked like a charm. Thanks man! 
The documentation of React Navigation is misguiding though. This feature is documented under v5.x but not stated that it's available on >= v5.7.x

Comment: I just created a pull request for the docs to show the minimum version.

Answer (score 6):

Acording to document you dont use in tab/ drawer navigation. You use only Modal and other areas.
"Note that this event is only triggered whenever a screen is being removed. For example:

The user pressed back button on a screen in a stack
The user performed a swipe back gesture
Some action such as pop or reset was dispatched which removes the screen from the state
This event is not triggered when a screen is being unfocused, but not removed. For example:

The user pushed a new screen on top of the screen with the listener in a stack
The user navigated from one tab/drawer screen to another tab/drawer screen"

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to go back?", [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => null,
          style: "cancel",
        },
        { text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() },
      ]);
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);
```

you can add this code which you dont want to go back on android. Gesture handling is not helpful on android. This is the link: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/
and on the documentation there is a link for android: https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler